# Bathroom faucets

Tags: plumbing, bathroom

Yesterday a pipe on the hot water heater blew. I turned off the shut off valve that goes to it so water wouldn’t overfill the drain. When I did that it left us with cold water in the house but not hot. I fixed the hot water pipe and turned it back on and now we have water everywhere in the house but the bathroom sinks. What would cause the cold water and now the hot water to not work in both bathrooms all of a sudden?

Comment: Did you check the aerators to make sure they didn't get clogged up?

Comment: Hello, and welcome to Home Improvement. Unfortunately, we'll need more info before we have any chance of helping you.

Comment: If the aerators were clogged, wouldn't that also stop the cold water? Question for the original poster:  When turned on full hot, do you get any water at all in those sinks?   Any other changes?

Comment: Agreed with Jack, also you need to clean all faucets and flush your line at the farthest fixture.

Comment: @GeorgeAnderson OP says afterwards cold and hot water not working...

Comment: Thanks, Jack, I obviously miss-read it. I now agree: Clean and flush.

Comment: @GeorgeAnderson  BTW.. liked your panel... stay safe